# R: Creating a function usingthe control structure 'for'

Tags: r

I would like to create a function that, having a vector (v) and a number (n), analyze if any of the numbers of 'v' is divisible by 'n', if it is, the function would have the outcome 'TRUE'. How could I use the control structure 'for' for it?

So far I've solved this problem using the 'while' operator:

```
function.while <- function(v, n){ 
while (n %% v == 0)
 return (TRUE)
}
```

But I can't fully understand the logic of 'for'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `for` loop like below :

```
function.for <- function(v, n){ 
  result <- logical(length(v))
  for(i in seq_along(v)) {
    result[i] <- v[i] %% n == 0
  }
  return(result)
}

function.for(1:10, 2)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

However, this is vectorised operation and you don't need `for` loop.

```
function.vectorized <- function(v, n){ 
  v %% n == 0
}
function.vectorized(1:10, 2)
```

---

If you want to check if `any` value is present.

```
function.vectorized <- function(v, n){ 
  any(v %% n == 0)
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that the outcome should be TRUE if any of the numbers is divisible, not all. Apologies for my explanation.

Comment: You can wrap `any` around the function. `any(function.for(1:10, 2))`